# How to override Chrome new tab content with a react component

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a React application/Chrome extension which overrides the content of a new tab in Google Chrome. I have used `create-react-app` and am simply trying to override the content of a new tab with `App.js` content. The folder structure is straight from the initial `create-react-app`, which is below.

```
    build
    node_modules
    Public
      favicon.ico
      index.html
      logo192.png
      logo512.png
      manifest.json
    src
      App.css
      App.js
      app.test.js
      index.css
      index.js
      logo.svg
    ..
    ..
```

My `manifest.json` file looks like this.

```
    {
      "name": "..",
      "author": "..",
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "manifest_version": 2,
      "description": "..",
      "chrome_url_overrides": {
        "newtab": "index.html"
      }
    }
```

This is what my `index.html` looks like.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />

    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />

    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

My `index.js` file looks like this.

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

I have tried inserting the following but receive an empty page.

```js
<script src="../src/index.js"></script>
```

How would I override the content of a new tab with `App.js`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Originally I modified my `manifest.json` file to the following.

```
{
  "name": "..",
  "author": "..",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "..",
  "chrome_url_overrides": {
    "newtab": "index.html"
  },
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'YOUR HASH'; object-src 'self'"
}
```

The `YOUR HASH` can be found from the console, as highlighted below

[image: Highlighted hash from console]

However, I went for an alternative approach. I created a `.env` file in the root directory and placed the following inside of it

```
INLINE_RUNTIME_CHUNK=false
```

Answer (score 1):

In case some have missed this step, you also need to build the app and load the build file into chrome extensions.

After changing `manifest.json` in the public folder and adding a `.env` file in the root directory as described by Corbuk, run `npm build`. Next, drag the build file into `chrome://extensions/` or import it with the `Load unpacked` button